# how do i get the id immediately after inserting the data?

Tags: django, django-views

I hope the title is enough to understand what my problem is,

I have this code in my views.py

```
enroll = StudentsEnrollmentRecord(
            Student_Users=student,Old_Student=old,New_Student=new, Payment_Type=payment,ESC_Student=esc,Last_School_Attended=last,Address_OF_School_Attended=add,
            Education_Levels=educationlevel,School_Year=schoolyear,Courses=course,strands=strands,Student_Types=stype,GWA=gwa
        )
    enroll.save()

 studentenrolment = StudentsEnrollmentRecord.objects.filter(Student_Users=enroll)
 return render(request, "print.html", {"studentenrolment":studentenrolment})
```

This is the error i get

[image]

this is my print.html

```
{% for i in studentenrolment %}
    <tr>
<tr>
        <td>SURNAME</td>
        <td colspan="6"><input type="text" size="107" value="{{i.Lastname}}" style="border:none" readonly></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>FIRSTNAME</td>
        <td colspan="6"><input type="text" size="107" value="{{i.Firstname}}" style="border:none" readonly></td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use **`enroll`**

```
enroll = StudentsEnrollmentRecord(
    Student_Users=student,
    Old_Student=old,
    New_Student=new,
    Payment_Type=payment,
    ESC_Student=esc,
    Last_School_Attended=last,
    Address_OF_School_Attended=add,
    Education_Levels=educationlevel,
    School_Year=schoolyear,
    Courses=course,
    strands=strands,
    Student_Types=stype,
    GWA=gwa
)

enroll.save()

return render(request, "print.html", {"studentenrolment": enroll})
```

```
# print.html
<tr>
<tr>
    <td>SURNAME</td>
    <td colspan="6"><input type="text" size="107" value="{{ studentenrolment.Lastname }}" style="border:none" readonly>
    </td>

</tr>
<tr>
    <td>FIRSTNAME</td>
    <td colspan="6"><input type="text" size="107" value="{{ studentenrolment.Firstname }}" style="border:none" readonly>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: when i tried this , i get this error """ 'StudentsEnrollmentRecord' object is not iterable """

Comment: `enroll` is a *single object*, not a queryset and hence it is not an iterable (not a list like object). Can you show your `print.html`?

Comment: i just copy paste your answer, but i receive this error """ 'StudentsEnrollmentRecord' object is not iterable """

Comment: please check my update question, I just post my some of my print.html

Comment: to get rid of the error, remove the *for loop* and use **`studentenrolment`** instead of **`i`**